# Enabling SSL in asp.net 4.0 and IIS 7.5

Tags: ssl, asp.net

I have created an asp.net 4.0 project. I want to enable SSL for it. Do I need to map this web project to new website in IIS. When I try to create a new website, I get:

The binding '*:80:' is assigned to another site. If you assign the same binding to this site, you will only be able to start one of the sites. Are you sure that you want to add this duplicate binding?

I am trying to follow the following posts:

```
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/06/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates.aspx

http://mscrm4humans.wordpress.com/2010/06/24/enabling-ssl-on-iis-7-0-using-self-signed-certificates/
```

my IIS is 7.5.7600....
I am totally new to SSL in asp.net. Please suggest solution to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you created a new site in IIS and are trying to set it to use port 80, which will already be in use by the Default Web Site. If you have nothing in the default site, simply stop it, and you will be able to assign 80 to your project. After that, you can obtain your cert, and apply it to that site.